# can't select and update my SDK API 33 in the SDK Manager

Tags: android-studio, sdk

The SDK Manager shows "update available" for Android 13, but i can't select it...
Can anyone tell me why?

Also, what does API level 33-ext4 or 33-ext5 mean? Should i install them?

i have the newest version of android studio, just downloaded and installed the update.
I can select other apis and i successfully selected and updated a few SDK Tools

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - box next to position "Android Tiramisu (Tiramisu)" was empty, Status was "Update Available" and wasn't able to interact with it in any way.

Solution was to select "Show Package Details" in the bottom of the window and after that each API category can be expanded to show its components. Under there box next to "Android SDK Platform 33" had a line inside and clicking it I was able to either change it to tick (install update) or make the box empty (uninstall the package).